# match values with different dates data.table

Tags: r, data.table, finance

I have an issue I just dont seem to be able to solve.
the issue is the following: my data looks approx like this, it's a data.table:

```
    Code       Date Marketvalue CommonEquity FiscalYearEnd
 1: 13643N 2001-03-30       44.01        26761    2001-09-30
 2: 13643N 2001-04-30       35.21        26761    2001-09-30
 3: 13643N 2001-05-31       48.82        26761    2001-09-30
 4: 13643N 2001-06-29       31.74        26761    2001-09-30
 5: 13643N 2001-07-31       32.01        26761    2001-09-30
 6: 13643N 2001-08-31       20.27        26761    2001-09-30
 7: 13643N 2001-09-28       15.20        26761    2001-09-30
 8: 13643N 2001-10-31       18.14        18618    2002-09-30
 9: 13643N 2001-11-30       22.14        18618    2002-09-30
10: 13643N 2001-12-31       18.67        18618    2002-09-30
11: 13643N 2002-01-31       21.34        18618    2002-09-30
12: 13643N 2002-02-28       18.19        18618    2002-09-30
13: 13643N 2002-03-29       19.47        18618    2002-09-30
14: 13643N 2002-04-30       17.34        18618    2002-09-30
15: 13643N 2002-05-31       13.07        18618    2002-09-30
16: 13643N 2002-06-28        7.47        18618    2002-09-30
17: 13643N 2002-07-31        7.47        18618    2002-09-30
18: 13643N 2002-08-30        6.46        18618    2002-09-30
19: 13643N 2002-09-30        5.87        18618    2002-09-30
20: 13643N 2002-10-31        6.67        13728    2003-09-30
21: 13643N 2002-11-29        4.16        13728    2003-09-30
22: 13643N 2002-12-31        3.47        13728    2003-09-30
23: 13643N 2003-01-31        3.36        13728    2003-09-30
24: 13643N 2003-02-28        3.36        13728    2003-09-30
25: 13643N 2003-03-31        2.61        13728    2003-09-30
26: 13643N 2003-04-30        3.04        13728    2003-09-30
27: 13643N 2003-05-30        3.84        13728    2003-09-30
28: 13643N 2003-06-30        4.43        13728    2003-09-30
      Code       Date Marketvalue CommonEquity FiscalYearEnd
```

what I want to do: each june of each year t I want to match the common equity of the fiscal year which ended in t-1 with the market value of the previous december.
now getting the marketvalue of the previous december is not that hard: I used the shift function with n= 6L to shift the december market values to june, but how do I do it with the common equity?
eg: for june 2002, the fiscal year end of that fiscal year is in 2002-09-30, but I need the common equity of the fiscal year which ended in t-1, in this case of 2001-09-30 (the value is 26761, see commonequity column). 
can anybody help me out on this? I unfortunately dont have any code of my own for this problem as I simply dont know how to adress the fiscal year end issue :(

thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I included an expected output:

```
      Code       Date Marketvalue CommonEquity FiscalYearEnd BEMERatio
 1: 13643N 2001-03-30       44.01        26761    2001-09-30        NA
 2: 13643N 2001-04-30       35.21        26761    2001-09-30        NA
 3: 13643N 2001-05-31       48.82        26761    2001-09-30        NA
 4: 13643N 2001-06-29       31.74        26761    2001-09-30        NA
 5: 13643N 2001-07-31       32.01        26761    2001-09-30        NA
 6: 13643N 2001-08-31       20.27        26761    2001-09-30        NA
 7: 13643N 2001-09-28       15.20        26761    2001-09-30        NA
 8: 13643N 2001-10-31       18.14        18618    2002-09-30        NA
 9: 13643N 2001-11-30       22.14        18618    2002-09-30        NA
10: 13643N 2001-12-31       18.67        18618    2002-09-30        NA
11: 13643N 2002-01-31       21.34        18618    2002-09-30        NA
12: 13643N 2002-02-28       18.19        18618    2002-09-30        NA
13: 13643N 2002-03-29       19.47        18618    2002-09-30        NA
14: 13643N 2002-04-30       17.34        18618    2002-09-30        NA
15: 13643N 2002-05-31       13.07        18618    2002-09-30        NA
16: 13643N 2002-06-28        7.47        18618    2002-09-30  1433.369
17: 13643N 2002-07-31        7.47        18618    2002-09-30        NA
18: 13643N 2002-08-30        6.46        18618    2002-09-30        NA
19: 13643N 2002-09-30        5.87        18618    2002-09-30        NA
20: 13643N 2002-10-31        6.67        13728    2003-09-30        NA
21: 13643N 2002-11-29        4.16        13728    2003-09-30        NA
22: 13643N 2002-12-31        3.47        13728    2003-09-30        NA
23: 13643N 2003-01-31        3.36        13728    2003-09-30        NA
24: 13643N 2003-02-28        3.36        13728    2003-09-30        NA
25: 13643N 2003-03-31        2.61        13728    2003-09-30        NA
26: 13643N 2003-04-30        3.04        13728    2003-09-30        NA
27: 13643N 2003-05-30        3.84        13728    2003-09-30        NA
28: 13643N 2003-06-30        4.43        13728    2003-09-30  5365.418
      Code       Date Marketvalue CommonEquity FiscalYearEnd BEMERatio
```

we dont have a bemeratio for june 2001 as we dont have a marketvalue from december 2000 in our data table, but for june 2002 and june 2003.
basically: each june: divide the common equity of the fiscal year which ended in the previous calendar year by the market value of the previous december. in this example for june 2002: 26761 (common equity of the fiscal year which ended in 2001) divided by  18.67 (the marketvalue of december 2001).

for june 2003: 18618 (common equity of the fiscal year which ended in 2002) divided by 3.47 (the market value of december 2002)

Comment: Can you please include your expected output for the sample data you give. I'm struggling to understand your prose explanations.

Comment: will do immediately

Comment: I have tried this, but my issue is: I just go back to the previous fiscal year value, but sometimes the fiscal year ends in march or april of the year, then I need to go back 'two' values, to march or april of the previous calendar (!) year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach using `data.table`:

```
#calculate the prev fiscal year end date for self joining later
DT[!is.na(FiscalYearEnd), 
    PrevFiscalYearEnd := as.Date(vapply(FiscalYearEnd,
            function(x) seq(x, by="-1 year", length.out=2L)[2L],
            numeric(1L)), 
        origin="1970-01-01")]

ans <- DT[!is.na(FiscalYearEnd), BEMERatio := 
    #get the CommonEquity for each fiscal year end
    unique(DT[!is.na(FiscalYearEnd), .(Code, FiscalYearEnd, CommonEquity)])[
        #join to find the previous fiscal year end common equity
        DT[!is.na(FiscalYearEnd)], on=c("Code", "FiscalYearEnd"="PrevFiscalYearEnd")][,
            #calculate ratio (need to make sure data is complete so that shifting by 6 months is robust)
            CommonEquity / shift(Marketvalue, 6L)]
    ]
```

output:

```
      Code       Date Marketvalue CommonEquity FiscalYearEnd PrevFiscalYearEnd BEMERatio
 1: 13643N 2001-03-30       44.01        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 2: 13643N 2001-04-30       35.21        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 3: 13643N 2001-05-31       48.82        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 4: 13643N 2001-06-29       31.74        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 5: 13643N 2001-07-31       32.01        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 6: 13643N 2001-08-31       20.27        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 7: 13643N 2001-09-28       15.20        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 8: 13643N 2001-10-31       18.14        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30  760.0398
 9: 13643N 2001-11-30       22.14        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30  548.1565
10: 13643N 2001-12-31       18.67        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30  843.1317
11: 13643N 2002-01-31       21.34        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30  836.0200
12: 13643N 2002-02-28       18.19        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30 1320.2269
13: 13643N 2002-03-29       19.47        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30 1760.5921
14: 13643N 2002-04-30       17.34        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30 1475.2481
15: 13643N 2002-05-31       13.07        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30 1208.7173
16: 13643N 2002-06-28        7.47        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30 1433.3690
17: 13643N 2002-07-31        7.47        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30 1254.0300
18: 13643N 2002-08-30        6.46        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30 1471.1930
19: 13643N 2002-09-30        5.87        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30 1374.4735
20: 13643N 2002-10-31        6.67        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30 1073.7024
21: 13643N 2002-11-29        4.16        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30 1424.4836
22: 13643N 2002-12-31        3.47        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30 2492.3695
23: 13643N 2003-01-31        3.36        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30 2492.3695
24: 13643N 2003-02-28        3.36        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30 2882.0433
25: 13643N 2003-03-31        2.61        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30 3171.7206
26: 13643N 2003-04-30        3.04        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30 2791.3043
27: 13643N 2003-05-30        3.84        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30 4475.4808
28: 13643N 2003-06-30        4.43        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30 5365.4179
      Code       Date Marketvalue CommonEquity FiscalYearEnd PrevFiscalYearEnd BEMERatio
```

if you really need months outside of June to be NA:

```
ans[month(Date)!=6L, BEMERatio := NA_real_]
```

output:

```
      Code       Date Marketvalue CommonEquity FiscalYearEnd PrevFiscalYearEnd BEMERatio
 1: 13643N 2001-03-30       44.01        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 2: 13643N 2001-04-30       35.21        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 3: 13643N 2001-05-31       48.82        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 4: 13643N 2001-06-29       31.74        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 5: 13643N 2001-07-31       32.01        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 6: 13643N 2001-08-31       20.27        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 7: 13643N 2001-09-28       15.20        26761    2001-09-30        2000-09-30        NA
 8: 13643N 2001-10-31       18.14        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30        NA
 9: 13643N 2001-11-30       22.14        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30        NA
10: 13643N 2001-12-31       18.67        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30        NA
11: 13643N 2002-01-31       21.34        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30        NA
12: 13643N 2002-02-28       18.19        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30        NA
13: 13643N 2002-03-29       19.47        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30        NA
14: 13643N 2002-04-30       17.34        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30        NA
15: 13643N 2002-05-31       13.07        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30        NA
16: 13643N 2002-06-28        7.47        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30  1433.369
17: 13643N 2002-07-31        7.47        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30        NA
18: 13643N 2002-08-30        6.46        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30        NA
19: 13643N 2002-09-30        5.87        18618    2002-09-30        2001-09-30        NA
20: 13643N 2002-10-31        6.67        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30        NA
21: 13643N 2002-11-29        4.16        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30        NA
22: 13643N 2002-12-31        3.47        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30        NA
23: 13643N 2003-01-31        3.36        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30        NA
24: 13643N 2003-02-28        3.36        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30        NA
25: 13643N 2003-03-31        2.61        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30        NA
26: 13643N 2003-04-30        3.04        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30        NA
27: 13643N 2003-05-30        3.84        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30        NA
28: 13643N 2003-06-30        4.43        13728    2003-09-30        2002-09-30  5365.418
      Code       Date Marketvalue CommonEquity FiscalYearEnd PrevFiscalYearEnd BEMERatio
```

Comment: thank you for this, I tried to analyze my issue, but I get the error:  `Error in seq.int(r1$year, by = by, length.out = length.out) : 
  'from' must be a finite number´ in the first part of the code. I tried to find out what the problem is, might you have any idea?

Comment: can you do a `DT[, unique(FiscalYearEnd)]` and see if there are NAs

Comment: yes, there are. sorry for not being clear enough about this. I have NAs in all columns except for the Code column and the Date column.

Comment: added handling for NA fiscal year end. can you try it again?

Comment: best case: if I dont have fiscal year end data which end in t-1 then I dont need the BEME ratio for that company in year t. If later I have fiscal year end data then they should be included.

Comment: this worked perfectly, thank you so much, I should have come up with the is.na myself, thanks again, you are a life saver. :)